# Is there a way to make a diagram in Illustrator and have it editable in other programs?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, diagram

What I'm trying to do is make a diagram in Illustrator.  Once it is finished it would be given to the customer but saved in a way so if sometime down the road they need to make changes to it they can.  But instead of them using Illustrator or any of the Creative Cloud applications, is there other software that would let them edit it easily?

Edit: I'm also looking for either free software or one that is included in a pack such as Microsoft Office

Comment: you can write eps or svg, use inkscape or do it in word.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you save it as eps your customer can open it in inkscape which is free and open source.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, if your client would know how to do this editing they would have known to specify an application. If on the other hand they do not have an application at hand then its unlikely that they would be doing the change easily.

So realistically you need to ask your client what they would want to use. Remember to charge extra for this as your releasing sources with your stuff. Add a section in your contract on how much you charge them for teaching how to use the design or if you don't in fact do this. Thread carefully there's a chance they they will counter that they could have done this themselves.

I mean sure you could use MS Visio, PowerPoint or Word to do this. But im sure you are aware why you wouldn't want to use those. For one no CMYK support, which may or may not be important. Or you could use Inkscape or yed.

You can copy paste stuff from illustrator to other applications just don't expect people to actually edit those. If you want to use a external software you need to design in that software.